# how to translate datebase tables(sqlite3) to numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, sqlite

a datebase contained 80 tables ,every table is a 18000x4 matrix ,how can I translate these to a 80x18000x4 numpy array?

the db : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3bNSNFik5wGdm1DYnJwNHBJMVU

I wrote a function. Do you have any better idea?

```
import sqlite3 as sql
import os
def db_to_array(db,r,c):
  db = sql.connect(db)
  cursor = db.cursor()
  cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
  tables = cursor.fetchall()
  wd=os.getcwd()
  if not os.path .exists(wd +'/temp/'):
    os.makedirs(wd +'/temp/')
  for table_name in tables:
    table_name = table_name[0]
    table = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from %s" % table_name, db)
    table.to_csv(wd +'/temp/'+ table_name + '.csv', index_label='index')
  ss=os.listdir(wd +'/temp/')
  print(len(ss))
  dd=np.empty([len(ss),r,c])
  for i in range(len(ss)):
    ddd=np.array(pd.read_csv(wd +'/temp/'+ss[i]))
    print(i)
    print(ddd.shape)
    dd[i,:,:]=ddd[:,0:r]
  return dd
```

Comment: By table do you mean 4 fields and 1000 records?  Show a sample table definition, and how you would select some records.  For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914215/exporting-data-from-sqlite-to-numpy-array

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I wrote a function. Do you have any better idea?